# Resize UIView and rotate when change orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a viewController that is presented to the screen and I set the orientation to Landscape using

`- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}`

In the same Xib file of the view of this viewController I have another view that is set to be on the top, like this
[Normal Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOJ7y.png)
The view itself should not rotate but when I change my orientation I want this view that has the slider to rotate and go to top.

I receive the notification of orientation changed using
`[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];`

First I tried to change the width of the frame of this view using `view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, 44);` and rotate it using transform but I got something like this [after resize width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rtuyt.png)

Clearly I lost the things on the right of the view I don't know why (since I have some constraints that I put in the interface builder that tell the label of the right to stay in the right of the view)

After this I tried to scale the view but I got something like this [I can't post more than 2 links but everything in the view become smaller (that's exactly what scale should do but it is not what I want)]. I wanted that the labels in the right and left stayed with the same width and only the slider to become smaller when I resize the width of the view.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use autolayouting ?

here is a screenshot how you could set autolayouting for your view

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use `autolayout`. give top,leading,trailing and fix height constraints to that slider and it will manage portrait and landscape both. hope this will help :)

Comment: I can't use autolayout because I have to fix my orientation and change only the place of the controls.

What I ended up doing was creating another xib only for the controls and then I could rotate them.

Thanks for the answer anyway =)